# is it right to say " it's the best of me ever been"?

Tags: grammar

Is it right to say "it's the best of me ever been"? or "it's the best of me ever being" in  biography, in order to say you are happy with your life now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many past participles can be used as adjectives to say the same as "that has been X".

> This is the best beer ever created.

However, *been* generally does not work like that, it's used only in verb forms.

> This is the best beer ever been

So, you have to use a phrase beginning with *that* instead.  Typically the subject of the previous clause is close enough where you don't have to specify the subject again.

> This is the best beer that ever was (or has ever been).
>
> It's the best of me that has ever been.

---

Grammatically this is OK:

> it's the best of me ever being.

The problem is that *to be* means to exist, but nothing much more than that.  So the meaning of being happy with one's life doesn't really come through, you're just saying you are existing in the best way possible.  Trees and other inanimate objects do that.

> I'm the happiest I've ever been with my life.

is probably what you want to say.

Answer (score 2):

No. You might say instead,

> "It is the best I have ever been."

or

> "I am now the best version of myself I have ever been."

or

> "I am happier with my life now than I have ever been."